# problem in showing the map in android app

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am trying to show a particular place in my android app. I have generated the Fingeprint key and submitted it to Google and got back an API key.

But still in my coding there are lot of errors, the errors mainly in the following import files

```
{import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;  
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;  
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;  
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;  
import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;}
```

the following is the code of my app

```
{  
public class ViewMap extends MapActivity  
{  
    MapView mapView;  
    MapController mc;  
    GeoPoint p;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapview);


        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
        View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

        zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

        mc = mapView.getController();
        String coordinates[] = {"1.352566007", "103.78921587"};
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

        p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setZoom(17); 
        mapView.invalidate();        
    }

     protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() 
     {
            return false;
     }
}

}
```

I have lot of errors inside the coding too, such as in GeoPoint, mc,MapView etc

Please help me solve this issue

Comment: do i have to add any new packages com.google.android with class files such as MapView,GeoPoint etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you select Google APIs for your target - refer to the image shown here
[image]

Comment: no i have not done it and Google Api is not been listed in my Properties. How to get it

Comment: ya i have not done it, thanx just now i am installing the packages

Comment: ya sure... Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.gis.ss/com.gis.ss.ViewMap}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gis.ss.ViewMap in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@4357f4d8
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)

Comment: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gis.ss.ViewMap in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@4357f4d8

Comment: at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1100)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a line like this in your manifest file?

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

And you may want to override the isRouteDisplayed unless your actively providing route information

You would need at least these to do much in mapview

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
```

Comment: do i have to add any new packages com.google.android with class files such as MapView,GeoPoint etc....

Comment: Actually all the ones in above error output which to me with my tired eyes looked like unformatted code

Answer (score 1):

Is your project build target targeting Google APIs or Android APIs?

Just in case you need to know, rightclick on your project, go to Properties->Android

If you do not have Google APIs, go to Window-> Android SDK and AVD Manager-> Available Packages -> Third Party Addons and you should be able to see it

Comment: ya i have not done it, thanx just now i am installing the packages