# How to create database application for Android?

Tags: android, database

I am developing an Android application where I want to make a database.
I have extended the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class but it's not working for me. Can anybody tell me how to make database through it or any other syntax or code? Please provide me some good tutorial or example to study the database creation and implementation in the application.

Here is my logcat file from an attempt to follow a `vogella.de` tutorial:

```
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.vogella.android.todos.database/de.vogella.android.todos.database.TodoDatabaseHelper}: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.vogella.android.todos.database.TodoDatabaseHelper
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1544)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: de.vogella.android.todos.database.TodoDatabaseHelper
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1536)
06-17 13:20:11.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1474):     ... 11 more
06-17 13:20:12.004: WARN/ActivityManager(68):   Force finishing activity de.vogella.android.todos.database/.TodoDatabaseHelper
```

Comment: @Adil can u check the ttutiral at http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html its same it has four classes so would be too many classes to display

Comment: did you just copied the code or you imported the project into eclipse...?

Comment: Would you look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo)... is your issue is same as in this thread...? if so than follow the thread and let us know...!!

Comment: one thing diffrenr Adil there exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException  and my exception                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Comment: @JaydeepKhamar Thank you for fixing the formatting, but please do not add things like “please help” or “thank you” to questions, and remove them if you see them. Like [signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures), these do not carry any information, they're just fluff. Please read [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial on Android + Database usage that interests you.

http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/

A very detailed explanation here:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 2):

Here is some tutorial for you.

> http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html
>
> http://sree.cc/google/android/creating-sqlite-database-tables-in-android

If you googling with "SQLite Tutorial for Android", there will be about 3,620,000 results 
 in less than 1 second.

Comment: @ Thanx for reply HERO i have tried the code of vogella.de but it crashes earlie it was showing null pointer exception whe was entering data but now it just crahes can you suggest somthing on basis of my logcat file

Answer (score 2):

i Suggest the Android Notepad tutorial about making a content provider.

[Sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html)

[Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)