# location-based application development testing on actual device

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I am trying an example given in o reilys book and testing it on LG P500 but all I get is force close with the following errors:

```
WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-11-09 15:43:38 - dloc] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2.2)
**p.s i have mentioned api level**
**logcat:**
11-09 16:00:44.738: W/dalvikvm(8002): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.microjobsinc.dloc/com.microjobsinc.dloc.Main}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microjobsinc.dloc.Main in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.microjobsinc.dloc-2.apk]
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microjobsinc.dloc.Main in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.microjobsinc.dloc-2.apk]
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
11-09 16:00:44.738: E/AndroidRuntime(8002):     ... 11 more
11-09 16:00:49.848: W/dalvikvm(8013): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
11-09 16:00:49.858: E/AndroidRuntime(8013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

**Code is written below**

```
public class main extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // find the TextViews
        TextView tvLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);

        TextView tvLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);
        // get handle for LocationManager

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // connect to the GPS location service
        String providerName = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation( providerName);
        // fill in the TextViews
        tvLatitude.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
        tvLongitude.setText(Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
        }

    }
```

What is the cause of this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the android project properties to use Google Apis with the platform version that you desire.