# Unable to instantiate ComponentInfo / ClassNotFound

Tags: android

I looked at many different questions but my problem only occurs on Android Versions lower than   Honeycomb.

I run JellyBean and ICS and my app works perfectly on it but when I try to run it on Gingerbread or Froyo i get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dragamstudios.waarisdezon/com.dragamstudios.waarisdezon.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

I use Android Studio as my IDE and tried exporting everything and deleting the /gen /out folder as described here:

[AndroidRuntime: Unable to instantiate activity: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983821/androidruntime-unable-to-instantiate-activity-java-lang-classnotfoundexception)

The weird thing is that it only occurs on older versions.

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is a newer IDE isn't it?  I use eclipse, and the only time errors like this occur for me is when:

1. I forgot to declare an activity in the Android manifest.
2. I didn't tell eclipse to export a dependency.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I did that. But it did not make any difference :/

Comment: Are you testing this in an emulator or a physical device?

Comment: Im thinking it could be something with the support library v4. But cant really figure it out

Comment: Maybe. Sincerely wish I could be of more help here. Is it actually claiming it can't find ComponentInfo? That class has been around a while... there's not an underlying error masking that one is there? If all else fails, sometimes an udpate or full reboot fixes things magically ;)