# Issues while lauching emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, graph

Right now i am trying to create a graph in android by self learning.After did some searches on Google i got some ideas.It recommends me to use some library or jar files for creating graphs or charts on android.Like wise i got kichart WinRAR file from this [link](http://www.kidroid.com/kichart/).

After emulator getting run,its just toasting as **"sorry your application has stopped unexpectedly.please try again.force to close"**

Can any one please help me to overcome this issue?
Please find my sources for reference.

**MainActiviy.java**

```
package com.example.z_chart;

import com.kidroid.kichart.ChartActivity;
import com.kidroid.kichart.model.Aitem;
import com.kidroid.kichart.view.LineView;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends ChartActivity 
{
LineView lv = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

String[] arrX = new String[4];
arrX[0] = "2010.1";
arrX[1] = "2010.2";
arrX[2] = "2010.3";
arrX[3] = "2010.4";

float[] arr = new float[4];
arr[0] = 100;
arr[1] = 150;
arr[2] = 380;
arr[3] = 300;


Aitem[] items = new Aitem[1];
items[0] = new Aitem(Color.RED, "Payout", arr);

lv = new LineView(this);
lv.setTitle("Money balance in four months");
lv.setAxisValueX(arrX);
lv.setItems(items);
setContentView(lv);
}}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
08-17 11:08:53.473: W/dalvikvm(345): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/z_chart/MainActivity; (414)
08-17 11:08:53.473: W/dalvikvm(345): Link of class 'Lcom/example/z_chart/MainActivity;' failed
08-17 11:08:53.523: D/AndroidRuntime(345): Shutting down VM
08-17 11:08:53.523: W/dalvikvm(345): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.z_chart/com.example.z_chart.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.z_chart.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.z_chart-1.apk]
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.z_chart.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.z_chart-1.apk]
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
08-17 11:08:53.604: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  ... 11 more
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.z_chart"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance!..

Comment: check whether mainactivity is declared in manifest..

Comment: @Ramkiran i checked out Manifest file and i declared mainactivity on manifest file. I have edited my question with manifest.xml file.Please find above.

Comment: This is a problem with using an external class. I can't remember how to fix it at the moment but it has something to do with the build path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Clean your Project and then check again.

Click on Project -> Clean in Eclipse.

Clean the project and build it again , so that the R.java is updated and doesn't uses any cached files

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4688277/614807) you can find different different solutions.

### or

Remove this line from your code.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```