# Android error for starting activity

Tags: android, runtime-error

I am trying to start an activity from another activity and I recieve an error and the application force closes.
Here is logcat:

```
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.example.higlightvoice.Boicemain$4.onClick(Boicemain.java:187)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-07 11:28:35.021: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 11:28:35.031: W/ActivityManager(61):   Force finishing activity com.example.higlightvoice/.Boicemain
10-07 11:28:35.598: W/ActivityManager(61): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40589670 com.example.higlightvoice/.Boicemain}
10-07 11:28:46.781: W/ActivityManager(61): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{40589670 com.example.higlightvoice/.Boicemain}
10-07 11:29:04.002: D/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

And here it is my code that how I call activity:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Boicemain.this,draw.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

And this is my activity I try to call:

```
public class draw extends Activity {
drawview drawView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set full screen view
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    drawView = new drawview(this);
    setContentView(drawView);
    drawView.requestFocus();
}
}
```

Comment: You're missing the actual exception (top line of logcat stacktrace)...

Comment: you need to provide us source code for your `Boicemain.onPause()` and `Boicemain.onDestroy()` methods

Comment: i haven't implemented onPause or onDestroy method!

Comment: Please post your AndroidManifest.xml (or have you declared your activity in this file?) and the Exception name in your logcat, thanx

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you didn't put the top most error on that log, i think you didn't define your activity on your AndroidManifest.xml.. to better examine your error, kindly put all the error log starting from the top part