# Android what needs to go in the onCreate method

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this code in my main activity class

```
public class HomeScreenActivity extends Activity {

    private Button contactButton;
    private Button groupContactButton;
    private Button historyButton;
    private Button optionsButton;
    private ListView contactsView;

    public static int selectedContactIndex = -1;

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    List<Contact> contactList = db.getAllContacts();
    ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

        contactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contactButton);
        contactButton.setSelected(true);
        groupContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.groupContactButton);
        historyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.historyButton);
        optionsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.optionsButton);
        contactsView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsView);

        // Set up contact adaptor so the contact list can be viewed in the
        // homescreen   

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this,
                R.layout.home_screen_contacts_view, contactList);
        contactsView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

And it is not working, here is the logcat:

```
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contactmanager/com.example.contactmanager.HomeScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:235)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.example.contactmanager.DatabaseHandler.getAllContacts(DatabaseHandler.java:111)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.example.contactmanager.HomeScreenActivity.<init>(HomeScreenActivity.java:27)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
09-28 22:02:47.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
```

I used to have my code working when I had put these three lines in the onCreate method but the reason I changed it is that I need to access these variables inside listeners so I need them to be class variables.

```
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        List<Contact> contactList = db.getAllContacts();
        ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
List<Contact> contactList = db.getAllContacts();
```

To this:

```
DatabaseHandler db;
List<Contact> contactList;
```

And add this to `onCreate()`:

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
contactList = db.getAllContacts();
```

Cheers.

Comment: thanks for the reply it worked. Why is this working? I'd really like to understand.

Comment: Because you are initializing the variables with `getApplicationContext()` before android gets a chance to actually create the context. That's why always initialize, if using Android APIs, inside the `onCreate`. and don't forget the check mark :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the activity is in your manifest file, and has proper permissions

Here is another person having the same problem: [java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo)

Here is example code: (You will have to adjust the 'path to activity' to correctly match your file, and the label.

```
<activity 
    android:label="@string/SOME STRING FOR YOUR LABEL"
    android:name=".PATH TO ACTIVITY GOES HERE.HomeScreenActivity ">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I had this problem previously and I have included this in my manifest file, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Activity do not  a have a  public constructor. On the inheritance line Activity got `getApplicationContext()` from [ContextThemeWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) and ContextThemeWrapper default constructor is defined as

```
public ContextThemeWrapper() {
         super(null);
     }
```

And, on Android documentation Context is defined as

```
Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system.
```

This also means that on Activity `onCreate()` method Android system provide the `getApplicationContext()` implementation. so if you call on `getApplicationContext()` before you will get an NPE.

And, to avoid this just create a global reference.