# why this runtime is occured :Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo?

Tags: android, spinner, runtimeexception

when I try to define an spinner, this Run time exception is thrown. Why?[image]
[image]

Comment: oh，you cannot do this like instance a object at out of onCreate.   you need to instance object at onCreate Method

Comment: You should call findViewById(int) after you call setcontentview(layout resId); Move the code after setContentView will work

Comment: Move pointed line after setContentView in onCreate method

Comment: **Never** post images of your code or the logcat, copy and paste it there instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize your spinner in the onCreate method, so move

```
CARS_TYPE = (Spinner)findViewById(...);
```

inside onCreate() after setContentView

one more thing, CARS_TYPE should not be a constant, better if you call it carsType instead