# How to fix errors after import project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I had a project in Android Studio. After reinstalling my OS I want to import my project again to Android Studio but I am getting this error:

**LogCat error:**

```
01-17 12:10:03.567 
13228-13228/com.nimaroid.introsliderproject 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nimaroid.introsliderproject, PID: 13228
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.nimaroid.introsliderproject/com.nimaroid.introsliderproject.IntroSliderActivity}: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nimaroid.introsliderproject.IntroSliderActivity" on path: 
    DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nimaroid.introsliderproject-1/base.apk", 
    zip file "/data/app/com.nimaroid.introsliderproject-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],
    nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nimaroid.introsliderproject-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nimaroid.introsliderproject.IntroSliderActivity" on path: 
    DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nimaroid.introsliderproject-1/base.apk", 
    zip file "/data/app/com.nimaroid.introsliderproject-
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nimaroid.introsliderproject">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".IntroSliderActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ads">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please add your Activity (IntroSliderActivity) in your  AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Has already been added

Comment: Could you share your manifest.xml file?

Comment: u can see now .

Comment: is your package name correct? or share your full manifest

Comment: package name is for another android studio . I just opened the project in new android studio but can`t run project(installation failed) then i use clean project and rebuild project . after this steps project run but get above error .

Comment: have you tried changing your theme element in the your activity in manifest? @NimaKhalili

Comment: i think the problem is package name because i test another project and still same error

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo) can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, but maybe it will not worked for everyone.

In similar situations, the problem will sometimes be solved by updating Android Studio following the steps below.

1. update Android Studio;
2. open project;
3. update `Gradle`(if the project is build in old version);
4. update `compileSdkVersion` & `targetSdkVersion` to last version;
5. update libraries to last version.

Note: The steps above are manual, but by default, Android Studio gives you the necessary messages to perform these steps.