# My android app is giving a long error and is not starting

Tags: java, android, xml

I am getting an error while trying to run my app in my emulator

I am following a tutorial that shows you how to make an app like WhatsApp but I am having some trouble. Whenever I try to run the app in my emulator I get this really long error that I can't seem to solve. The only thing I changed that might've been of importance was the file name. It was MainActivity.jk or tk I forgot. But I changed it to MainActivity.Java. But this is the error I keep getting.

04-19 13:30:10.485 3614-3614/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chatster, PID: 3614
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chatster/com.example.chatster.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.chatster.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.chatster-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.chatster-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.chatster.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.chatster-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.chatster-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.chatster;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected Bundle savedInstanceState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Chatster");
}

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="com.example.chatster">

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo)

Comment: Add Screenshot of your project structure, so that we can see in which package does your MainActivity exist.

Comment: I can't because there is something wrong with my computer but it's under the android tab. app\java\chatster\com.example.chatster\MainActivity.Java

Comment: did you try putting in app/src/main/java/com/example/chatster/MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be problem in your case.:  The relative path of your `activity` in manifest is not correct or your didn't declare your activity in your `androidManifest`

```
<activity android:name="com.example.chatster.MainActivity"
```

Please try to remvoe this line from your `onCreate()`

```
this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState ;
```

After you did this please clean and rebuild your project and restart your android studio

Please check this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo&ved=2ahUKEwj7__ah69zhAhUkyYUKHartAo0QFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw0stEy1eQKQlVtlNMEwoRnX) for more information and hope you will resolve the problem

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put my android manifest file in there take a look at it now

Comment: try to declare your activity as i wrote above with the package

Comment: I added that line. Then I cleaned the project, then I rebuilt it and it still doesn't work

Comment: Yes. Still the same one

Comment: Clean rebuild amd restart your android studio !

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Disable instant run in Android Studio.

**Go to File -> Settings/Preferences (Mac) -> Build Execution and Deployment -> Uncheck Instant Run**

Then Clean and rebuild the project.

[image]

Comment: Is your multidex enabled to true in gradle file?

Comment: there is no multidex in my gradle files

Comment: Ok, did you try Invalidate cache and restart from File option in Android Studio? If not could you check.

Comment: Yes I did try that