# Unable to instantiate activity. I only connect the library

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I'm new at this
I just create standart app (hello world), which works. After that I try to use library. I add this line to my build.gradle:
`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'`
And immediately I get an error when I try to launch the application: "p4 has stopped", "p4 keeps stoping".
Logcat looks like that:
**2020-10-23 15:34:35.646 20799-20799/com.example.p4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.p4, PID: 20799
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.p4/com.example.p4.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.p4.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.p4-OHm5vpOPjFrHTDRMlOcCig==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.p4-OHm5vpOPjFrHTDRMlOcCig==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.p4.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.p4-OHm5vpOPjFrHTDRMlOcCig==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.p4-OHm5vpOPjFrHTDRMlOcCig==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.p4-OHm5vpOPjFrHTDRMlOcCig==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.p4-OHm5vpOPjFrHTDRMlOcCig==/base.apk': Bad method handle type 7
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:100)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:74)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:157)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:64)
at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:676)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:709)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:936)
at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2242)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5672)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
... 6 more**
I hope this information is enough. I don't know what else to show
My manifest looks like that:
`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo

Comment: I read this thread earlier but I did not understand what kind of activity to add. @DeepParsania

Answer (score 1):

you have not defined your activity in your Manifest file.

Comment: I did not understand what kind of activity to add. edited the question my manifest looks like this